# Is there a simple way to authenticate WPF Desktop application with Office 365 API?

Tags: c#, wpf, api, azure, office365

I want to create simple WPF desktop or console application which retrieves and shows data from Office 365 Contacts API.

I already have an Azure AD and an Office 365 accounts. I've read the documentation and seen a lot of samples. But they were all about ASP.NET and windows 8.1 and other types of application.
They used OWIN or build-in authentication calls(for windows 8.1).

I think it should look like this:

1. User presses the button
2. My application calls a method from "some Microsoft library" and passes as
   client_id a parameter. This call will open a new browser window with
   suggestion for user to login. User logs in and agrees to provide access to  his contacts.
3. As result of this call I should receive an access token
4. Be happy and read contacts by using
   Microsoft.Ofiice365.OutlookServices.

I'm stuck at the second point of this idea - "some Microsoft library".
Can you suggest which library I should use?
Does something like this exist?

If it would not work in this way, can you suggest any other way to retrieve contacts from office 365 in WPF desktop or console application?

I'm trying to find something that is [like this,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn631817.aspx) but works wiht contacts API (not with One Drive) and does not require me to define special BrowserWindow in XAML or C#.
Does this way exist?  Or I should implement this functionality by myself?

Additionally I would like to use Office 365 REST API, not EWS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this from a Windows app. I'd recommend using [ADAL](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.16.204221202) for the authentication. That should provide a browser window for the signin process. You can also use the [Visual Studio Office 365 Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15b85e6-69a7-4fdf-adda-a38066bb5155) to register your app and get libraries for calling the Contacts API.